# limma making contrasts appropriately in single-channel micro-array

Tags: r, matrix, bioinformatics

I have a microarray dataset with and I have labeled the data such that it looks something like this:

```
[9967] piRNA          piRNA          piRNA          piRNA          piRNA          tiRNA         
[9973] piRNA          piRNA          piRNA          piRNA          piRNA          tiRNA         
[9979] snoRNA          snoRNA          snoRNA          snoRNA          snoRNA          snoRNA         
[9985] tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA         
[9991] tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA         
[9997] tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA          tiRNA
```

So basically I have a bunch of different probe-types in a single-channel micro-array and I want to make a contrast to see which are DE.

I have tried to do this as follows:

```
design<-factor(levels(probe.type1))
design<-model.matrix(~0+design)
dim(design)
dim(E.ncRNA1)
subE.ncRNA1<-E.ncRNA1[ ,1:12]
fit<-lmFit(subE.ncRNA1, design)
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(levels=design)
trying <- contrasts.fit(fit, contrast.matrix)
try <- eBayes(trying)
try<-eBayes(trying)
volcanoplot(trying)
```

The problem occurs where I try to make the contrasts:

```
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(pivsmi=piRNA-miRNA, levels=design)
```

> Error in makeContrasts(pivsmi = piRNA - miRNA, levels = design) :  The
>   levels must by syntactically valid names in R, see help(make.names). 
>   Non valid names: designputative miRNA,designsub scRNA,designvault RNA

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In R, [a syntactically valid name](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/make.names.html) consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number.

Your levels(`designputative miRNA`, `designsub scRNA`, `designvault RNA`) contain spaces, so are not syntactically valid.

To make your levels syntactically valid, either

- replace the spaces in your levels with e.g. underscores, or
- call `make.names` on your levels, which replaces the spaces automatically with a dot:
  `makeContrasts(pivsmi = piRNA - miRNA, levels = make.names(design, unique=TRUE))`. 
  The `unique=TRUE` asserts that the resulting elements are unique, this is desired for column names.